# How to check if any background process is utilizing the internet connection?

Tags: internet, background-process

My internet speed is 4 Mbps. In Windows, I get 2 Mbps download bandwidth, but in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I only get a maximum of 20 Kbps. Why is it so?

Is there any background process which might be utilizing the internet connection? If yes, then how do I know that?

[image]

Comment: check if its matter of networking http://askubuntu.com/questions/192654/i-need-a-good-network-monitoring-tool/261494#261494

Answer (score 5):

If you want the information in a Terminal you can run `sudo lsof -i` which will tell you all open internet connections (and listening processes too).

Your screenshot shows no anomaly, nothing unexpected (except maybe *tomcat*). So take one more step to investigate: you are going to look at actual bandwidth used in any connection with external hosts.

For this you need to

- install *iftop* by typing `sudo apt-get install iftop`
- run it with `sudo iftop` (or maybe `sudo iftop -i wlan0` if the first command gives an error)

You will get a picture like

[image]

where the top line shows the overall used bandwidth (here very little bandwidth is used at the moment).

Comment: the problem is still persist sir, how do I overcome this? sometimes the download speed shows in Bps not even in 1 Kbps, or am I doing anything wrong with Ubuntu?

Comment: thanks is there a way to see the actual download link being downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

To find if there’s a process to utilize Internet, close your browser or any other applications you know, then Open **System Monitor > Resourses [tab]** and check for **Recieving** and **Sent** amounts. There should be **0** as you see below:

[image]

Comment: I closed all the applications still the network history shows some amount of bytes sending and receiving sir