# Network activity monitor

Tags: networking, monitor, monitoring

I would like to ask you, if you know any SIMPLE and LIGHTWEIGHT application for monitoring network?

I am not looking for network activity monitor for servers, like daily stats etc, i need realtime stats.

I mean that it shows how much bytes are incoming and outgoing of EVERY SINGLE APP..

I would like to have that program with **GUI**.. something like this in Windows:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need a good network monitoring tool](http://askubuntu.com/questions/192654/i-need-a-good-network-monitoring-tool)

Comment: It is not, because that network monitoring apps are for servers, because they shows statistics, but i need realtime monitoring with GUI of applications :)

Answer (score 2):

Have you reviewed gnome-system-monitor?  It has real time monitoring.

Comment: But it doesn't shows real time network traffic by application, it shows only overall network traffic

Comment: THAT is the one I wanted.  Thank you from July 2017