# Installation and configuration of an SNMP client

Tags: snmp

I want to install a SNMP client (NOT AGENT) on my computer so I can connect to a Cisco Router on which an SNMP agent is already installed.

The problem that all the documentation I found for Ubuntu were for installing an agent not a client.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool to pull SNMP statistics from the Cisco router from your computer? Like a MIB browser?

Comment: actually, for my internship i have to develop a tool to supervise the IP flow, something like nagios or cacti, so i can't install them i have to do something like that.

Comment: i want to collect info from the cisco router via the commands "get" et build a data base that i can use later.

Comment: hmm. OK. IP flows are very different(i.e. NetFlow, s-flow, or cflowd). Can you do an snmpwalk of the Cisco router MIB tree from your command line? Is this what you need to get set up?

Comment: basiclly what i want to do is to communicate with the MIB's router to get infos and store them in a data base. of course to do so i need an SNMP client on my computer+mbrowse and an SNMP agent on the router. the problem that every time i do "get-apt install snmp snmpd mbrowse" it does not work and i don't know why. please help me

Comment: Be sure to use `sudo apt-get install <package-name>`. Also, take a look at my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141564/what-is-snmp-used-for/252994#252994 as well as the link in there on to how to enable SNMP. You probably do not need to install the snmp just configure it correctly(on both the router and your desktop).

Comment: thank you a lot i'll try your link. if it does not work can i ask you again for help??

Comment: i've try it, but the problem is now clear: it's about the apt-get install because i have the same error message

Comment: please can i show you the error message. i can't understand it, i think it has something to do with the sources.list

Comment: You need to use some MIBs. So look at these links: [cisco.com/public/sw-center/...](http://www.cisco.com/public/sw-center/netmgmt/cmtk/mibs.shtml) And [tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/...](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseMIB.do?local=en&step=2)

Answer (score 8):

As suggested, you should use snmpwalk or snmpget in a script.
The package containing snmpwalk and snmpget is "snmp" and the correct syntax for install is:

```
sudo apt-get install snmp
```

instead of "get-apt install snmp snmpd mbrowse"

After install, you can do a complete snmpwalk to discover wich of the informations you need from your cisco device and later filter them using snmpwalk otions.

Example:

```
snmpget -v1 -c public 192.168.0.254 .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.14.11.5.1.1.2
```

Hope this helps!